# Show previous fragment after entering Picture-In-Picture

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture

I have the following navigation structure in my app:

```
 MainActivity    ->    VideoListFragment     ->      VideoShowingFragment
(only activity,     (shows a list of Video      (gets the URL of the video to 
 container for       items via a Recycler-        show and plays the video via 
 all the other       View, the URL of the         ExoPlayer. From here, the user
 fragments)          Video is passed to           can enter PiP mode)
                     next Fragment)
```

So, when the app starts, a list of Video items is shown to the user. When the user clicks on an item, the URL is passed to the VideoShowingFragment which displays the Video content to the user via the PlayerView of the ExoPlayer library. On top of the PlayerView, there is an icon so the user can enter PiP mode when he clicks on it.

Entering PiP works and is all fine, but how can I show the list of Videos after going to PiP mode? What I mean: When the user is in the VideoShowingFragment stage and decides to minimize the Video content by entering the PiP mode, how can I show him the list of Videos (VideoListFragment) so that he can browse through the list while still watching the content in PiP mode?

The situation right now is the following: The user enters PiP mode but the user sees the Start Screen of his device while the video content is minimized in the bottom right corner.

Comment: So you want everything before your `VideoShowingFragment` to be full screen behind your video player in picture in picture mode?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean